# POST method of rest web api

Tags: rest, url, post, asp.net-web-api

The POST method can be used by any third party tool like ajax, http client, rest client but can POST method be run by web browser Address URL?

Comment: It's unclear, what you are asking. Update your question with more details

Comment: @ChristianSt. Can Post method of Web API be run by any URL in web browser as we can do for GET method? same question for PUT and Delete also.

Answer (score 2):

No, the address bar will only do a GET.

You need a form, or ajax to do POSTs.